# PDOException::("could not find driver") on windows

Tags: php, windows, pdo, xampp

I understand that there are already many questions about this error, and even there are answers, but none of them helped me, a year ago I tried to start studying laravel and there was all the same error, I abandoned this thing, now I decided to try again, I even windows reinstalled.
**What have i been through:**

1. uncomment the line extension = php_pdo_mysql.dll, more precisely, I initially had it without ";
2. changed the php version, now there is php version 7.4.4, and in xampp version 7.4.4
3. DBMS works correctly, tested on pure php, using MariaDB

I repeat, I use windows it is very important, because in almost all the answers I see this line "sudo"

Comment: I'm not familiar with xampp but are there multiple versions? If so you should add what you are running. Also if unclear how the upgrade to 7.4.4 was done should add that as well. Could have just update CLI while version xampp uses is still running old version.

Comment: Create a simple php script containing just this `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` Run it and look at the parameter `Loaded Configuration File` Is that the `php.ini` file that you edited

Comment: OH MY GOD, I really changed the file in xampp itself and not in php ...Thank you, it worked!